# embeding od condition in xsl when getting error

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

below is the xsl tag on which I am getting the error as i have used `xsl:when` intead of `xsl:if` , folks please advise how can I re correct it so that i do not get compilation exception while transforming the xsl again I am using xslt 1.0

```
<xsl:when test="abcid=dec_id">
        <xsl:for-each select="$qq_Obj/ert_Period/ytr_Period">
            <xsl:variable name="ABC_Rate">
            <xsl:value-of select="$Sds/oht_Period/rew_Period/@vgRate" />
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$iue_first=@vgRate">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'AAA'" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:value-of select="'BBB'" />
            </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:when>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose the "else" part of an `xsl:choose` in an `xsl:otherwise`:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$iue_first=@vgRate">
        <xsl:value-of select="'AAA'" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="'BBB'" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```